# set input attributes to readonly except for one

Tags: css, attributes

I have the following line of code that is supposed to make all `input` fields editable except for the input field with `class` name `emp_id` using jquery:

```
$(['input']:not(.emp_id)).attr('readonly',FALSE);
```

But it does not really work for me! I really appreciate if anyone could help me what i am missing in this!

Answer (score 0):

`$('input:not(.emp_id)').removeAttr('readonly');` should work, assuming all your inputs are `readonly` to start with.

http://jsfiddle.net/ULsHc/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the point in here:

```
$('input:not(.emp_id)').attr('readonly', false);
```

and

```
$('input:not(.emp_id)').attr('readonly', FALSE);
```

It seems like the work false and FALSE in this statement are not the same. This code works fine with false. The capital form FALSE is not working!